# UIPageViewController: Swipe registration

Tags: ios, uikit, swift2

I would like to achieve an animation when swiping from page to page on a `UIPageViewController`. I would like this animation to be linked to a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`.

My question is: can I calculate a beginning and end of a swipe gesture and relatively execute an `CGAffineTransform`?
So I during the swipe, I want to `transform` a view in the direction of the swipe.

Who has any good tutorials or snippets I could use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things.

Page view controllers are not built to use custom animations between pages. They are intended to use either a slide animation or a page curl animation.

Second, swipe gestures are single-shot, not continuous. There is no "relatively execute." When you do a swipe gesture, nothing happens, then the gesture fires and it's over. If you want an animation that's proportional to the user's finger position in the gesture you'll either need to do some specialized handling of a pan gesture recognizer or create your own custom gesture recognizer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Does that mean I can subclass something to create my own transition instead of a horizontal scroll?

Comment: According to the docs UIPageViewController can be subclassed in iOS 6 and later. I've never tried, but since you can subclass it you probably could change the transition style.

Comment: You should look into the UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator protocol. That's the "modern" way to customize view controller transitions. I don't know if a page view controller uses it or not since page view controllers predate transition coordinators. You might want to take a look at Matt Neuburg's book "Programming iOS 9". It looks like it covers this sort of thing in detail.

Comment: You can read about @matt's book at http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920044352.do?green=47A450BB-116F-5379-B03C-D23FFE13DD78&intcmp=af-mybuy-0636920044352.IP Sounds like it might meet your needs. I've pinged him - perhaps he can chime in.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Duncan! I have the book now, but I can't figure out at page 342 where I should do the `self.transitionFromViewController()` call?

I personally am thinking I should place it in the container view controller in which I create an instance of the `UIPageViewController`, in the method `viewControllerAtIndex:index` which I use to return a `UIViewController` for the given index or return nil if the index is out of range.

Comment: As I said previously, I'm not sure if it's possible to use a TransitionCoordinator with a page view controller. I was suggesting that it would be worth investigating.